# Vue loading spinner change to bars/dots in laravel vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I've been following the reference below and I've already implement this on my project, but the problem is I want to change the loading from `spinner` into `dots` or `bars`. Currently I have this output which is the default spinner. It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

Reference documentation [Vueloadingoverlay](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay)

[image]

Based on the documentation, just simply add `:loader="bars"` under `<loading>` tag but it didn't work for me, here's my code.

*Import.blade.php:  `<Loading>` Tag area*

```
<div class="vld-parent">
    <loading 
        :loader="bars"
        :active.sync="isLoading" 
        :can-cancel="false" 
        :is-full-page="fullPage">
    </loading>
    <div class="kt-portlet__body">
        <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
            Download example import format!. <strong><a href="">import.xlsx</a></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="row">            
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ __('staff/forms.stocks_upload') }} </label>                
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file" accept=""/>                
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Choose file</label>                
                    </div>
                    {!! $errors->first('file', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
                </div> 
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kt-portlet__foot">
        <div class="kt-form__actions">        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="loadingEvent()" style="margin-top: 40px;">{{ __('staff/buttons.import') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*import.js*

```
 module.exports = function(data) {
    var _data = {
        config: null, 
        isLoading: false,
        fullPage: true   
    };
    return {
        data: (() => Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(data), _data)),
        mounted() {
            this.init();
        },
        methods: {
            init() {
                var vm = this;
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    vm.$toaster.init();                   
                });
            },
            loadingEvent(){
                this.isLoading= true;        //thi will show the spinner loader
            },
            onCancel() {
                this.loading= false;
              }
        },
        
    }
};
```

*I just separate the component and put the import in `app.js`*

```
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';

Vue.component('loading', Loading);
```

Comment: compile and hard reload may be

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul Yes I've already tried many times but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below has been snipped from the component's documentation.

Make sure you pass 'bars' prop as **string**.

| Attribute | Type | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loader | String | spinner | Name of icon shape you want use as loader, spinner or dots or bars |

In your code that should look like:

Option 1 (note the excluded colon and single quotes):

```
<loading 
    loader="bars"
    :active.sync="isLoading" 
    :can-cancel="false" 
    :is-full-page="fullPage">
</loading>
```

Option 2 (with dynamic prop - that's not necessary in your case):

```
<loading 
    :loader="'bars'"
    :active.sync="isLoading" 
    :can-cancel="false" 
    :is-full-page="fullPage">
</loading>
```

See more about dynamic props:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props